# How to access css variables in a different file?

Tags: import, css-modules, css-variables

I've created a global.css file and I've declared css variables in the :root element. Now I'd like to style my page modularly and to do that, I need to access variables like (--primary-color: #000) from the global.css file, but it isn't working.

I've tried to use @import '../styles/global.css' on top of the new css module and then use var(--primary-color) but the variable isn't accessible yet.

Is it possible to use css variables in another css file or only Sass can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having the same problem, I've found that when working with CSS Modules, any CSS file ending with .module.css is considered a CSS modules file. Importing such a file will return the corresponding module object.

So I solve the problem just adding .module.css to de end of the css file name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).